# Prefill fields of a widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to use a widget on my site. I don't have access to widget source code(minified, obfuscated). Widget works with my DOM inserting some divs, not frame. Widget is probably build with react(**react** prefixes on some divs).

Use case: user fiels widget form, click "send" and gets some feedback. To improve user experience, I want to prefill those fields.

There is no way to do it, according to widgets company.
I have no experience with react.

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Set a  value for input after DOM is ready -> partial working. Fields are prefilled, but values disappear if I try to change one of them. I think, values are stored somewhere else and only duplicated to inputs.
2. Tried to manually fire input events(change, focus, keyup) to initialize widget scripts after value change -> no result.
3. Tried to emulate keypress events -> run into browser security.

Is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to changing input values React does some trickery because it kind of overwrites the default getter/setter for `value` of an `input` element and it has its own value tracker. To make the changes get handled in React you need to use native `value` setter to provide new value for an input and then dispatch an input event:

```js
const App = () => <input id="input" onChange={({target: {value}}) => console.log(`input event handled in React with value: ${value}`)} />

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));

document.getElementById("dispatch-fake-event").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const inputEl = document.getElementById("input");
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set.call(
  inputEl,
  "new value"
);
  const event = new Event("input", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false
  });
  inputEl.dispatchEvent(event);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
<button id="dispatch-fake-event">dispatch fake event</button>
```

Comment: 'input' event is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Redux form is component of react which allows to collect data from
>   form and initialize the inital values also of the redux form, below is
>   the example with initial values of redux form hence the fields will
>   take that values as initial values when you want to prefill full or
>   partial data into forms. Also note that initial state can also be
>   empty

```
let InitializeFromStateForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, load, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
       // your components
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

// Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
InitializeFromStateForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'initializeFromState' // a unique identifier for this form
})(InitializeFromStateForm)

// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
InitializeFromStateForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.account.data // pull initial values from account reducer
  }),
  { load: loadAccount } // bind account loading action creator
)(InitializeFromStateForm)

export default InitializeFromStateForm
```

Please find the complete documentation example [here](https://redux-form.com/7.0.2/examples/initializefromstate/)

Comment: form initialization is probably done somewhere in widget code. How can i change the values without access to any variable names?

Comment: you can change the global state from anywhere and assign the initial state from global state